# MySQL Query Issue - Left Joins

Tags: mysql, left-join

Suppose i have three Tables "table A and table B",and data as follows:

DATA of  A and B

```
table A ID's : "3,4,9"
```

table B has following Data :

```
("3" "activeUser")
("3" "publicUser")
("4" "activeUser")
("9" "publicUser")
```

Now, what i want is:
if B.id exist in A and has attribute "activeUser" then my output needs to be "activeUser"
if B.id exist in A and has no attribute "activeUser" but has "publicUser" then "publicUser"

If B.id does not exist in A, and B.Id ha no attribute "publicUser" then my output need to be something like ("error" or other label)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks all,
But i still with one problem.. Suppose that B.Id does not exists in A.Id and B.Id has no attribute PublicUser.. In this case, i would be expected for example ("null") as output for this row In your solution, the output for this case will be "PublicUser", but isn't what i expected Is there any possible update in your solution to solve this problem? Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  B.id,
  CASE WHEN
    MAX(CASE WHEN B.attribute = "activeUser" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND COUNT(A.id)>0
  THEN
    'activeUser'
  ELSE
    'publicUser'
  END userType
FROM
  B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id=A.ID
GROUP BY
  B.id
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d994e/1).

I'm joining B with A using a LEFT JOIN, in order to return all rows from B and only rows from A that matches.

Then I'm grouping by B.id, and calculating `MAX(CASE WHEN B.attribute = "activeUser" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. If at least a rows associated to that ID has the attribute activeUser set, MAX() will return Null, 0 otherwise.

Then I'm counting the rows returned by `COUNT(A.id)`. If the id is present in A, COUNT will be > 0.

**Edit**

If I understand correctly your comment, I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  B.id,
  CASE WHEN
    MAX(CASE WHEN B.attribute = "activeUser" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND COUNT(A.id)>0
  THEN
    'activeUser'
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN B.attribute = "publicUser" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
         THEN 'publicUser' END
  END userType
FROM
  B LEFT JOIN A ON B.id=A.ID
GROUP BY
  B.id
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/feaf0/6).

Comment: Thanks.. your answer helped me.. But i still with one problem.. Suppose that B.Id does not exists in A.Id and B.Id has no attribute PublicUser.. In this case, i would be expected for example ("null") as output for this row In your solution, the output for this case will be "PublicUser", but isn't what i expected Is there any possible update in your solution to solve this problem? Many Thanks.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues please see my updated answer, i hope it is correct now

Comment: Well, still not exactly what i'm looking for.. For example.. B.Id=10, has the attribute "ActiveUser" but not exists in A.Id and the output is "publicUser" and that is not correct..  Sorry for my bad English fthiella.. In this particulary case, the output would be something like "error" ou other "label" .. thanks in advanced

Comment: Thanks fthiella your last solution is exactly what i'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

firstly welcome to StackOverflow (!)

As much as your question seems to be more *"to learn"* than *"to solve a problem of my company"*, I chose to use ENUM, which has advantages and disadvantages, as you may want to see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html).
I'm also making use of [primary keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html), [inline IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

---

DB design:

```
CREATE TABLE A (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE B (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  status ENUM('publicUser','activeUser') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publicUser',
  PRIMARY KEY(id, status)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES (3),(4),(9);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'activeUser'), (3, 'publicUser'),
(4, 'activeUser'), (9, 'publicUser'), (10, 'activeUser');
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  B.id AS `B_id`,
  IF (
    A.id IS NULL,
    'publicUser',
    IF (
      MAX(B.status + 0) = 2, 'activeUser', 'publicUser'
    )
  ) AS `result`
FROM B
  LEFT JOIN A USING (id)
GROUP BY B.id;
```

Regards,

Leonardo Assumpção

---

#### [Edit]

Considering our conversation, here's a first suggestion (or even a waste of time & brain):

[image: Diagram1]

Assuming it fits to your real purposes, a possible query to know which client is vip or not would simply be

```
SELECT
  c.id AS `client_id`,
  c.client_name,
  IF(c.is_vip, "active", "public") as `TEST`
FROM client AS c;
```

But maybe it's still wrong. Is there a direct relationship between partners and clients?
P.S: complete sql [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06d02/1)

Comment: Thanks.. your answer helped me..
But i still with one problem..

Suppose that B.Id does not exists in A.Id and B.Id has no attribute PublicUser.. 
In this case, i would be expected for example ("null") as output for this row

In your solution, the output for this case will be "PublicUser", but isn't what i expected

Is there any possible update in your solution to solve this problem?

Many Thanks.

Comment: One question, David, what's your table A for? And you mentioned a table C, would it be of any importance in this situation?

Comment: Remembering what you said, *If B.id does not exist in A, then my output need to be "publicUser"*...

Comment: Hi Leonardo, you are correct.. my mistake.
Now, once edited, have you any update to help me in this case?
Thanks Leonardo.

Comment: When a user situation changes, do you intend to remember it's old value? Maybe if we know the reason of table B we can design things more efficiently.

Comment: Hi Leonardo, my situation is simple or not.. I'm implementing and promotion system.. One Partner, should be able to submit public or private promotions about their products. Imagine that you have an public and private promotion about one product, and your client is in vip list (table A). In this case, the promotion por their client, is Private.  If you have an private promotion but zero vip client and no kind of public promotion, the promotion is none (zero). I hope this explanation will help Thanks.

Comment: You are brazilian, aren't you? (: You'll see lots of brazilians here.

Comment: :) Portuguese.. are you brazilian?

Comment: Sim, sou brasileiro. Mas creio que falar português por aqui é meio contra as políticas do site... E sobre o seu sistema, acredito que exista uma estrutura que se encaixe melhor à sua necessidade, vou inclusive atualizar a minha resposta com uma sugestão pra saber a sua opinião.

Comment: Olá, sim deve ser contra as regras.. a questão é que a resposta que me deram faz o que peço. O problema é que não consigo entender a lógica. Faz-me um pouco confusão tanto a tua solução com a outra.. Já trabalho à um tempo com mysql, mas nunca trabalhei com condiçoes no select. tenho de estudar mais este ponto.. De qualquer maneira obrigado Leonardo pela ajuda ;) Abraço